# Applying a material to an imported model [three.js]

Tags: three.js

Part of a project that I'm working on requires that I pull in an array of base64 images, then pull in imported models via THREE.JSONLoader(). If I keep these two types of assets apart, they both load without issue. However, if I try to apply the image as a material to the model, I get an error.

> WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'vWorldPosition' not read by fragment shader

I realize that much of the time when you load in geometry, you need to run geometry.computeTangets(), but that isn't working. I thought perhaps there's another computation that might need to run prior to creating a mesh with the geometry and the material. Here's what I have:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(data.images[0]),
        shininess: 4.0,
    });
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();            
loader.load("app/museum/geometry.json", function (geometry) {
    geometry.computeTangents();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.scale.set(100, 100, 100);
    mesh.position.y = 150;
    mesh.position.x = 0;
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

I assume there's an additional setting or method that needs to be called, or perhaps there are attributes in the geometry.json that I need to set manually?

Comment: What is the problem and what is the quesiton?

Comment: Problem: I can't apply a material to geometry I'm loading in.
Question: How do I make it so I can?

Comment: What is the value of 'data.images[0]' that you send to the loadTexture function?

Comment: It's a base64 string I'm pulling in from my backend. It has no problems applying to basic geometry, or just as 2d images, it's only running into problems with imported models.